# standard matrix for reflection along a line in R3

Tags: linear-algebra

Can determine the standard matrix representation in $\Bbb R^2$ for reflection along a given line but confused about doing this in $\Bbb R^3$.

in $\Bbb R^2$:

1. use line of reflection as vector **a** and derive perpendicular vector **b**
2. derive ordered basis matrix $[T]_B$
3. derive transition matrix $[P]_{S,B}$ and its inverse $[P]_{B,S}$
4. derive standard matrix  $[T]_S$ = $[P]_{S,B}$ $[T]_B$  $[P]_{B,S}$

For the $\Bbb R^3$ problem, the line along which reflection takes place is part of $(0,0,0)$ to $(x,y,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative method, using change of basis.

Let the line (passing through) the origin be

$\ell(t) = t V $

We can assume that $V$ is a unit vector, if it is not, then we can always normalize it by dividing it by its Euclidean norm.

Now construct a new basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ using the unit vector $V$ and two unit vectors $U_1$ and $U_2$ that mutually orthogonal and also orthogonal to $V$.  Now the new set of vectors $\{U_1, U_2, V \}$ defines a new basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a corresponding $3 \times 3 $ orthogonal matrix

$ R = [U_1, U_2, V] $

Given a point $P \in \mathbb{R}^3$, the coordinates of $P$ in the new basis is given by

$ Q = R^T P $

Since we're reflecting about $V$ in the standard basis, we are effectively reflecting about the $z$-axis in the new basis.  Hence, the reflected point in the new basis $Q'$, can be obtained from $Q$ by negative the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.  That is,

$ Q' = \begin{bmatrix} -1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} R^T P $

Finally, the reflected point in the standard basis will be

$ P' = R Q' $

And this is equal to

$ P' = R \begin{bmatrix} -1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} R^T P$

Now substitute $R$, you get

$ P' = [U_1, U_2, V] \begin{bmatrix} -1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T \\ U_2^T \\ V^T \end{bmatrix} P $

This reduces to

$ P' = [- U_1, -U_2, V] \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T \\ U_2^T \\ V^T \end{bmatrix} P $

And further to

$ P' = \left( - U_1 U_1^T - U_2 U_2^T + V V^T \right) P $

Now recall that $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, therefore,

$ R R^T = I $

so that

$[ U_1, U_2, V ] \begin{bmatrix} U_1^T \\ U_2^T \\ V^T \end{bmatrix} = I $

that is,

$ U_1 U_1^T + U_2 U_2^T + V V^T = I $

So that

$ - U_1 U_1^T - U_2 U_2^T = V V^T - I $

Substituing this into the expression for $P'$, we obtain

$ P' = (2 V V^T - I) P $

So the standard matrix for this linear transformation is

$ A =  2 V V^T - I $

which is exactly the same result obtained in the other solution (recall that here $V$ is assumed to be a unit vector).

Comment: +1 thanks, I mentioned the special case of Line being formed by vector (x, y, 0) passing through origin

Comment: You're welcome.  You can apply the formula in my solution to your special case.

Answer (score 1):

Since the line you want to reflect about passes through the origin then its parametric equation is

$\ell(t) = t V $

where $V$ is its direction vector.  Now given a point (vector) $P(x, y,z) $, its orthogonal projection onto the line is

$ P_1 = \dfrac{ P \cdot V}{V.V} V $

The orthogonal complement is

$P_2 = P - P_1 = (I - \dfrac{ {V V}^T }{V^T V} ) P $

And finally the reflection of $P$ will be $P' = P - 2 P_2$

$ P' = (I - 2 (I - \dfrac{ {VV}^T}{V^T V})) P = \boxed{(2 \dfrac{{VV}^T}{V^T V} - I ) P } $

Thus the standard matrix is

$ A = 2 \dfrac{{VV}^T}{V^T V} - I  $

To verify this, let $V = [1, 2, 3]^T $ and $ P = [5, 1, 2]^T $, then

$ A = \dfrac{2}{14} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 3
\\2 && 4 && 6 \\3 && 6 && 9 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\
0&&0&&1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} -6 && 2 && 3 \\
2 && -3 && 6 \\ 3&& 6 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $

So the image of $P$ is

$P' =   \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} -6 && 2 && 3 \\
2 && -3 && 6 \\ 3&& 6 && 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} -22 \\ 19 \\ 25 \end{bmatrix} $

$ P' - P = \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} -57 \\ 12 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix} $

$ V \cdot (P' - P) = \dfrac{1}{7} ( -57(1) + 12 (2) + 11(3)) = 0 $

$ \dfrac{1}{2} (P' + P) = \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} 13 \\ 26 \\ 39 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{13}{7} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence, the line joining $P$ and $P'$ is perpendicular to $V$ and the midpoint of $ P P'$ lies on the line.  This verifies that $P'$ is indeed the reflection of $P$ about the given line.

Comment: as the reflection occurs along the line this could be solved via an eigenvector and eigenvalue approach?

Comment: thanks (+1) - was looking for a solution using a change in basis, ie obtain perpendicular vector b, then its reflection T(b), then its representation matrix under the existing basis and then the standard representation matrix

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  However, I think my solution provides the shortest way to implement the reflection.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128652/the-matrix-representation-of-a-reflection-operator-across-the-plane-x2y3z-0?rq=1

Comment: I have just posted another solution using change of basis.